# Where can I find solar radiation data for specific land areas?

Tags: meteorology, solar-terrestrial-physics

NOAA has solar radiation data for 1991-2010 http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/land-based-station-data/land-based-datasets/solar-radiation But I need data for Nov 1 2012-present! Is this data available?

Will I have to generate it myself? I have the software to do it, it is just a time/processor consuming task.

Comment: Maybe on [OpenData.se]

Answer (score 5):

The Measurement and Instrumentation Data Center (MIDC, http://www.nrel.gov/midc/) provides Irradiance and other Meteorological Data from several stations. Have you also check in: https://mapsbeta.nrel.gov/nsrdb-data-viewer/? Some of the data maybe until the end of 2012 used to be in http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/. Good luck!